# Trigger code issues with MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I have a trigger in the MariaDb Server with following code:

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER `set_app_number` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE newAppNo INTEGER;
        SELECT Max(id)+1 INTO newAppNo FROM table_name;
        SET NEW.application_number = newAppNo; 
    END; //
    DELIMITER ;
```

I am trying to create the same trigger on the production server where I have MySQL(5.7+ version). Where I am getting error like:

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 6 errors were found during analysis.
>
> - Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "CREATE TRIGGER " at    position 0)
> - Unexpected beginning of statement. (near    "`set_app_number`" at position 15)
> - Unexpected beginning of statement. (near " BEFORE INSERT ON " at position 39)
> - Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`table_name`" at position 57)
> - Unexpected beginning of statement. (near " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN" at    position 74)
> - Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "DECLARE    newAppNo INTEGER" at position 95)
>
> SQL query:
>
> CREATE TRIGGER `set_app_number` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name` FOR EACH
>   ROW BEGIN DECLARE newAppNo INTEGER
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'CREATE TRIGGER `set_app_number` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name`'
>   at line 1

I am not sure what's the exact issue here. Thanks in advance.

### ***Update***

When trying to add a trigger from phpMyAdmin using `More -> Trigger -> Add Trigger`, the very same code is generated. I am not sure why it is not allowing the same when executing it from SQL. :(

Comment: Tried changing INTEGER with INT(11), didn't worked.

Comment: What came _before_ `DELIMITER //`?

Comment: @RickJames nothing, the code starts from the DELIMITER itself

Comment: Use the mysql commandline tool, in which case you do need the `DELIMITER`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove delimiters a run it as query

```
CREATE TRIGGER `set_app_number` 
    BEFORE INSERT ON 
        `table_name` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE newAppNo INTEGER;
        SELECT Max(id)+1 INTO newAppNo FROM table_name;
        SET NEW.application_number = newAppNo; 
    END;
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you have direct acces to DB or through some web admin?